# cronolog apache on windows questions

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a website with only a vew virtual hosts on it and I'm very new to Apache.

Currently we use

```
Customlog "|bin/chronolog e:/Apache/log/access-%Y-%m-%d.log" combined
```

We typically once a week stop Apache and then zip the directory that's created with this and then restart Apache.

What I'm confused about is the stoping of Apache even necessary? After reading and seeing the | log, that the Apache service shouldn't need to be shut down in order to create a new log file. But since I have no idea what I'm doing with this, I wanted to ask first.

If it doesn't need to be stopped, I'm guessing I can just powershell a simple script to automate this once or twice a week and make this process a bit simpler?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to stop Apache for this. Linux systems use logrotate to automate what you've described, and there's a Windows version. [LogRotateWin](http://sourceforge.net/p/logrotatewin/wiki/LogRotate/)

I haven't tried it on Windows, but it seems worth a try.

Comment: I see the logrotate but from what I'm reading it's a huge memory hog and can cause horrible issues within a Windows server. 

Something I'd like to avoid as these are production servers with no test bed.

Answer (score 0):

ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l E:/logs/error.%Y.%m.%d.log 86400"

Is working correctly after I restarted the Apache service. Now I can just take the logs and run 7zip on the directory and I have them all.

Thanks for the tip as Rotatelogs does more of what I wanted than Chronologs